# PircBot with java need help creating relay bot?

Tags: java, irc

I would like help creating a relay bot with PircBot. I want it for each message it sends a message to a channel with that message. And I wish to have this multi networks. I made a command

```
if (split[0].equalsIgnoreCase(commandPrefix + "addnet")) {
    // sendRawLine("QUIT : joining " + split[1]);
    BrookieBot bot = new BrookieBot();
    bot.setVerbose(true);
    addnet = addnet + " " + split[1];
    try {
        bot.connect(split[1]);
        sendMessage("nickserv", "identify pass");
        bot.joinChannel("#brookies-use-of-bot");

    } catch (NickAlreadyInUseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IrcException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    bot = new BrookieBot();
    quit = 6;

    this.joinChannel("#brookies-use-of-bot");
}
```

That is how I made it connect to multiple networks, but I want it to reconise the net and send a message each time it recieves a message to that channel no matter what network. 
Having the message be in this format: `[<net>] [<sender>] [<message>]`. Thank you for all your help! I have this version: http://www.jibble.org/pircbot.php

Answer (score 0):

I've made one such relay bot before. Let's discuss what you need.

When a bot recieves a message in a channel to be relayed, the message is sent using an array of bots to their respective channels based on server and channel combination, provided:

1. The channel selected in the loop is not the current channel
2. The channel is in the list of to be synchronized channels
3. The sender is not part of the bot names to prevent infinite loops

The same goes for quit, part, join and anything else you want.

Answer (score 0):

1) PircBot isn't good for multi networks. Also, it has several design problems.
I would recommend PircBotX.

2) If you really have to use PircBot:

Create one PircBot object per connection.
That will create one thread per PircBot.
Then, create a bus which will distribute the messages amongst PircBot instances.
Be careful with synchronization.

For an example on how to send messages outside PircBot object, see [JawaBot](http://code.google.com/p/jawabot/), which is based on it.